# program not printing out correctly

Tags: java

i have a small inventory program. the three classes are listed below.  I think that when i add an item it is working correctly but when i choose the view option, it is not printing out what i want.

InventoryApp.java

```
package cockeb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class InventoryApp {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("\"add\"    - to add a product");
        System.out.println("\"remove\" - to remove a product");
        System.out.println("\"update\" - to update a product");
        System.out.println("\"view\"   - to view a product");
        System.out.println("\"quit\"   - to quit the menu");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.print("Please Enter Your Choice: ");
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        String stringInput;
        stringInput = userInput.nextLine();

        if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            break;
        } else if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("add") || stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {

            Product newProduct = new Product();
            InventoryManager inventory = new InventoryManager();

            System.out.print("Please enter UPC for the product: ");
            String upc = userInput.nextLine();
            newProduct.setUpc(upc);

            System.out.print("Please enter the short detail for the product: ");
            String sDetail = userInput.nextLine();
            newProduct.setShortDetails(sDetail);

            System.out.print("Please enter the long detail for the product: ");
            String lDetail = userInput.nextLine();
            newProduct.setLongDetails(lDetail);

            System.out.print("Please enter the price for the product: ");
            BigDecimal price = userInput.nextBigDecimal();
            newProduct.setPrice(price);

            System.out.print("Please enter the stock for the product: ");
            int stock = userInput.nextInt();
            newProduct.setStock(stock);

            if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
                inventory.addProduct(newProduct);
            } else if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
                inventory.updateProduct(newProduct);
            }
        } else if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("view") || stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("remove")) {
            System.out.print("Please enter the UPC for the product: ");
            String upc = userInput.nextLine();

            InventoryManager inventory = new InventoryManager();

            if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("view")) {
                inventory.getProduct(upc);
                System.out.println(inventory.toString());
            } else if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("remove")) {
                inventory.removeProduct(upc);
                System.out.println("UPC Has Been Removed");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Selection, Please Try Again");
        }
    }
}
}
```

InventoryManager.java

```
package cockeb;

import edu.lcc.citp.utility.CollectionFileStorageUtility;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class has lets you view, update, add, and delete items from the list
 *
 * @author brandon.c
 */
public class InventoryManager {

/**
 * List of all products stored
 *
 * @return - List of Products stored
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
public List<Product> getProductList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    return new ArrayList<>(CollectionFileStorageUtility.load(Product.class));

}

/**
 * Finds a product using the UPC
 *
 * @param upc - UPC of the product you are searching for
 * @return - The product
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
public Product getProduct(String upc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    Product matchP = null;
    for (Product p : getProductList()) {
        if (p.getUpc().equals(upc)) {
            matchP = p;
        }
    }

    return matchP;

}

/**
 * Lets user add a new product
 *
 * @param p - The new Product
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
public void addProduct(Product p) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    List<Product> pList = getProductList();

    if (getProduct(p.getUpc()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Product UPC Already Exists, Please Try Again");
    } else {
        pList.add(p);
        Collections.sort(pList);
        CollectionFileStorageUtility.save(pList, Product.class);
    }

}

/**
 * Lets the user change all fields except the UPC field.
 *
 * @param p - the Product with the same UPC
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
public void updateProduct(Product p) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    List<Product> pList = getProductList();

    Product matchP = null;
    for (Product pElement : pList) {
        if (pElement.getUpc().equals(p.getUpc())) {
            matchP = pElement;
        }
    }

    if (matchP == null) {
        System.out.println("Product UPC Does Not Exist");
    } else {
        if (p.getLongDetails() != null) {
            matchP.setLongDetails(p.getLongDetails());
        }
        if (p.getPrice() != null) {
            matchP.setPrice(p.getPrice());
        }
        if (p.getShortDetails() != null) {
            matchP.setShortDetails(p.getShortDetails());
        }
        if (p.getStock() != null) {
            matchP.setStock(p.getStock());
        }

        CollectionFileStorageUtility.save(pList, Product.class);
    }

}

/**
 * Lets the user to delete an item using the UPC
 *
 * @param upc - UPC of the Item
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */
public void removeProduct(String upc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

    List<Product> pList = getProductList();

    Product matchP = null;
    for (Product p : pList) {
        if (p.getUpc().equals(upc)) {
            matchP = p;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (matchP == null) {
        System.out.println("Product UPC Does Not Exist");
    } else {
        pList.remove(matchP);
        CollectionFileStorageUtility.save(pList, Product.class);
    }

}
}
```

Product.java

```
package cockeb;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class Product implements Serializable, Comparable<Product> {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String upc;
private String shortDetails;
private String longDetails;
private BigDecimal price;
private Integer stock;

public String getUpc() {
    return upc;
}

public void setUpc(String upc) {
    this.upc = upc;
}

public String getShortDetails() {
    return shortDetails;
}

public void setShortDetails(String shortDetails) {
    this.shortDetails = shortDetails;
}

public String getLongDetails() {
    return longDetails;
}

public void setLongDetails(String longDetails) {
    this.longDetails = longDetails;
}

public BigDecimal getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(BigDecimal price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Integer getStock() {
    return stock;
}

public void setStock(Integer stock) {
    this.stock = stock;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Product t) {
    return this.getUpc().compareTo(t.getUpc());
}

}
```

I am not getting any errors, but the output for this program is as follows:

```
"add"    - to add a product
"remove" - to remove a product
"update" - to update a product
"view"   - to view a product
"quit"   - to quit the menu

Please Enter Your Choice: add
Please enter UPC for the product: 123
Please enter the short detail for the product: car
Please enter the long detail for the product: big car
Please enter the price for the product: 200
Please enter the stock for the product: 2


"add"    - to add a product
"remove" - to remove a product
"update" - to update a product
"view"   - to view a product
"quit"   - to quit the menu

Please Enter Your Choice: view
Please enter the UPC for the product: 123
cockeb.InventoryManager@7ef20235
```

i want it to print out a list of any products i have entered.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: you'll need to override `toString` method inside for your `InventoryManager`, also make sure you're printing the correct result `System.out.println(inventory.getProduct(upc).toString());`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is that you're trying to print the `inventory` variable instead of the `product`. To fix this change the following line:

```
if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("view")) {
    inventory.getProduct(upc);
    System.out.println(inventory.toString());
}
```

To this:

```
if (stringInput.equalsIgnoreCase("view")) {        
    System.out.println(inventory.getProduct(upc).toString());
}
```

But since you haven't overridden the `toString()` method in your `Product.java` you'll get a memory representation instead. So you need to add the following to your `Product.java` to fix this.

```
public String toString() { 
    return upc + " - " + price; // or whatever you want.
}
```

Sample output:

```
Please Enter Your Choice: view
Please enter the UPC for the product: 123
123 - 999
```

Comment: @Spectre6 sure! Kindly mark the answer as correct if you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Your `InventoryManager inventory` is empty when you call `getProduct()`. And yes, your `toString()` needs to be call on the right element and be overrided.

Comment: so what do i have to do to fix it?  I am not getting any errors so i am having a hard time pin pointing the problem.

Comment: You are doing `InventoryManager inventory = new InventoryManager();` before printing the product you have added before, and you call your print on the new object, which is actually empty. You just have to initialize your `InventoryManager` object before your `while`, and then work on this object. You don't have to re-initialize it everytime. Here, you are only able to have one `Product` in your `InventoryManager`.

You can do it the way you are, but your `InventoryManager` class should follows the Singleton pattern.

Comment: Ok however its working because of CollectionFileStorageUtility .. My bad ! But still you can simplify it.